# session saved data not fetching in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am trying to get data in textbox if previously saved in session. When user enters page it will be blank. If he fills data & submit then I want If page loads again then it should take it from session values

```
Private Sub Online_Medicines_order_online_Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Session("patientName") Is Nothing Then
            patientName.Text = ""
        Else
            patientName.Text = Session("patientName").ToString
        End If

    End Sub

Private Sub orderButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orderButton.Click
    Session("patientName") = patientName.Text
    Session("address1") = address1.Text
    Session("address2") = address2.Text
    Session("landmark") = landmark.Text
    Session("zip") = zip.Text
    Session("mobileNumber") = mobileNumber.Text
    Session("city") = city.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: what is problem in your code ?

Comment: your code is proper.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani Problem is after reload it's not getting textbox data from session. It shows blank. I need to do this because while form submit it checks whether user login or not. if he is not login then it shows login property. Once login it take back to this page but because of postback textbox losses it's value. So that's why I need to store in session